# Using the Cyberduck --copy in Cyberduck CLI

Tags: cyberduck

I am trying to copy wordPress files between servers with --copy

It is however unclear to me which URL should be used as the origin and which as the destination?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Francois Wessels

Answer (score 1):

According to [Scripting cloud storage copy using the command line interface (CLI)](https://blog.cyberduck.io/2015/06/24/scripting-cloud-storage-copy-using-the-command-line-interface-cli/),

> Consider you want to copy files from Amazon S3 to Rackspace CloudFiles running OpenStack Swift, all you need is the command
>
> ```
> duck --copy s3://<Access Key ID>@<bucket>/ rackspace://<Username>@<container>/
> ```
>
> to copy all files.

So that would be "from" "to".